# Как преобразовать строку в десятичное число?

Tags: php

У нас есть строка "10.6". Как такую строку преобразовать в число 10.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К примеру. Так делается явное преобразование.

```
$foo ='10.6';
$bar = (float) $foo;
```

Но в большинстве случаях это не требуется PHP и сам может преобразовать типы.
[Больше тут.](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Answer (score 2):

Для разнообразия приведу пример, как сделать конвертацию в число с плавающей точкой, с фильтрацией исходной строки.

В большинстве случаев фильтрация **необходима**, поскольку PHP не выдаст ошибки, если вы попытаетесь преобразовать строку, не являющуюся представлением числа в число. Вместо этого вы получите `0.0`. (Этот факт совсем не очевиден для новичков.)

А вот и код:

```
$input = '10.6';
// Валидация.
if (!filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Неверный формат значения!');
}
// Собственно преобразование.
$float = (float)$input;
```

Comment: upvote за код, но вам не кажется что стоит это ещё обвернуть в `try catch` для новичков?

Comment: `try catch` нужно использовать для реальной обработки ошибок. Пустой `try catch` вряд ли чему-то научит новичка.

Comment: Может быть... Вообще если обвернуть в `try catch` ваш код то можно показать что вот это конструкция, обрабатывает именно это исключение. И так мы можем его отлавить а не выпасть в fatal с uncathing exception

Comment: `try catch` блок нужно использовать там, где происходит реальная обработка ошибок. Типичный пример: функция, выбрасывающая `\InvalidArgumentException` не должна **сама** обрабатывать это исключение. Что касается примера, то мы ничего не знаем о том, _к какому уровню_ принадлежит этот код. А раз так, то логично отдать обработку исключений коду на уровне выше. Нет уровня выше - нет обработчика исключений.

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = "10.6";
$int = (int)$num;
$float = (float)$num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию [floatval](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.floatval.php)

```
$val = "10.6"
$var = floatval($val)
```